# Mono stream issue

Tags: linux, image, stream, mono, nancy

I want to upload file on server using NancyFX. I do this:

```
var fileStream = File.Create(path_to_file);
file.Value.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
file.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
```

Also i tried:

```
byte[] buffer;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   file.Value.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   file.Value.CopyTo(memoryStream);
   buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ms.Position = 0;
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
img.Save(path);
```

And this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(coverPath, buffer);
```

On my Windows PC it works great. On the Linux server, image is saving, but the image content doesn't match to original image.
So, here are the images:
Original image, that is uploading: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTsE2.jpg
Saved image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORKn1.jpg
If image size is < 900kb, image is saving good, but some times there also appears that lines.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have a fileStream and you wanna save it as Image

here is a peace of code which works fine in Windows 8 .net 4.5 and Ubuntu 12 TLS with mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @"img/mTsE2.jpg";
        string destimationImage = @"img/dest.jpg";

        string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        string pathToFile = Path.Combine(appPath, fileName);

        if (!File.Exists(pathToFile))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cant find file {0}", pathToFile);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();




        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(pathToFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source length: {0}", fileStream.Length);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];

            fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

            memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("memoryStream length {0}", memoryStream.Length);

        string destPath = Path.Combine(appPath, destimationImage);
        CopyAsImage(destPath, memoryStream);

        Console.WriteLine("Done! Check file {0}",destPath);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CopyAsImage(string fileName, Stream stream)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);
        image.Save(fileName);


    }
}
```

if it still not work be aware of sizes . In fact int is a Int32 which should be ok for a byte array up to 2+Gigs

Comment: I can't initialize fileStream, cause I already have stream of file, which is coming from nancy request.

Comment: `using (Stream stream = file.Value)`

so, here comes next error:
`Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status) <0x00157>
at System.Drawing.Image.CreateFromHandle (intptr) <0x00027>
at System.Drawing.Image.LoadFromStream (System.IO.Stream,bool) <0x0002b>
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream (System.IO.Stream,bool,bool) <0x00013>`

Comment: the exceptions is thrown here: 
`Image image = Image.FromStream(stream, true, true);`
in `CopyAsImage` method

Comment: which version of mono you are running? what are params for mcs compile options? It is strange as on my local (see specification above) it running ok.

Have you tried to run example above on you linux environment?

Comment: Strange on my machine works fine, compiled on Windows and ran on ubuntu. Do you really need it to be Image, do you change it after loading or just you need to save it. May this link will help http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/serverprogramming/nancy-and-c-uploading-and/

Comment: using `file.Value.CopyTo(fileStream);` images, that have size more than 50kb are damaging during saving. after final saving, the image content is displaying in lines, see it here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ORKn1.jpg